# UWP DropShadow Stretch horizontally

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have a list in a UWP Application where I would like to add shadows to the list. That works so far, but when I add those the items are no longer stretch horizontally:

[image]
[image]

I already have defined this style:

```
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the default style of [DropShadow](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/DropShadowPanel/DropShadowPanel.xaml), since it sets the HorizontalContentAlignment property as Left, your listViewItem still can't stretch horizontally. So you also need to set the **HorizontalContentAlignment** of DropShadow as Stretch.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Lists,Mode=OneWay}" Background="AliceBlue">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0" ShadowOpacity="0.70"
                      OffsetX="5.0" OffsetY="5.0" Color="Black" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                ......
            </controls:DropShadowPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```